# VBA - Take two input dates, search a column for the dates, copy the range onto new sheet.

Tags: vba, excel

Sub All_Data()

Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
Dim match As Date

UserForm8.Show
    date1 = CDate(UserForm8.TextBox1.Value)
    date2 = CDate(UserForm8.TextBox2.Value)
Unload UserForm8

...

End Sub

Comment: What is your question???

Comment: Where do I begin? haha... I have tried various methods, but most result in error.

Comment: So you're using a userform - How is the userform being called? Why not just go right from the userform with an "OK" button to begin the searching? Once you have your two date values, you need to loop through the column you want to search for your values, then if it's a match, copy the entire row (or whatever range you're indicating) onto a new sheet.

Comment: You need to be more specific for us to help you. What date format are you using? Does the user know what date format to enter? This can cause all sorts of problems. How many rows in the column? Is this amount of rows dynamic or no? Details!

Comment: I apologize for the brevity. I am using a mm/dd/yyyy format. The user enters two dates and clicks submit. The submit button creates a new sheet. The code can be added to the submit button. The code I need to produce will refer to a sheet that will be added to with time, so there will not be a definite number of rows. The code should select all rows at or in between the desired dates. Copy all the data in the rows. Paste on the newly created sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have pasted the code, but nothing is copying over to the new sheet. What format should the dates in the "Data Table" be in?

Comment: Format's not important. Did you put in the sheet names? Note that sheet2 is the destination sheet, sheet1 is the source sheet.

Comment: I have entered the sheet names. The only problem is that nothing pastes on the sheet created.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could use to paste over whatever you need to another sheet. This only pastes over column A, but you can set the range to be longer if needed. The macro takes date1 and date2, finds all the rows inbetween the two dates and then transfers them to a new sheet.

```
Sub pastingdates()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim date1 As String
Dim date2 As String

date1 = UserForm8.TextBox1.Value
date2 = UserForm8.TextBox2.Value
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = date1 Then
        For j = i To 5
            If Range("A" & j).Value = date2 Then
                'Destination / _ Source
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i & ":A" & j).Value = _
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":A" & j).Value
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```